# express validation return [object object]

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

```
import {check, validationResult} from 'express-validator';

export const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Error(errors.array());
  }

  next();
};

router.post(
  '/register',
  [
    check('first_name').exists(),
    check('last_name').exists(),
    check('username').exists(),
  ],
  validate,
  (req, res) => {
    return res.json({status: 'success', message: 'Ok'});
  },
);
```

express validator return 500 [object Object] while console does correct print

```
[
  {
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value',
    param: 'last_name',
    location: 'body'
  },
  {
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value',
    param: 'username',
    location: 'body'
  }
]
```

How can we fix this please guide it should print what it is receiving into console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your middleware with response or create error middleware

```
export const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.json({error: errors.array()})
  }

  next();
};
```

Try this it should work

Answer (score 0):

`res.json({ 'status': 400, 'msg': errors.array()[0].msg});`

write console.log(errors) and find your error msg